# Select grouped by column only, not the aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, aggregate-functions

In a MySql select statement involving aggregation, is it possible to select **just** the grouped by column **without** the aggregate?

Basically I want to select IDs in subquery according to a criteria based on an aggregate, in this case the total payments to a client:

```
select idclient, business_name from client where idclient in
(
  select idclient, sum(amount) as total 
  from payment 
  group by idclient
  having total > 100
)
```

... but this fails with error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` because the subquery selects both the id (which I want) and the total (which I don't). Can I exclude `total` from the subquery result in any way?

Edit: if possible I would prefer to avoid using a join - the where clause is being passed onto another existing function on its own.

*Apologies if this is a dupe - I did search, honest. I couldn't find an exact answer in the mass of SQL aggregate questions.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
select idclient, business_name from client where idclient in
(
  select idclient 
  from payment 
  group by idclient
  having sum(amount) > 100
)
```

You need to put aggregate function in having clause and in sub query you need to select # of columns same as in your where clause.

Comment: thanks! I don't know where I got the idea that 'having' could only use selected columns :\

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE idclient IN (...)
```

The stuff inside `(...)` is a subquery.  Obviously it should only return one column, because you only need one column of data for the IN clause.

You can omit the total column by:

```
SELECT idclient
FROM payment
GROUP BY idclient
HAVING SUM(amount) > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this one:

```
SELECT c.idclient, c.business_name
FROM payment p
  INNER JOIN client c ON c.idclient = p.idclient
GROUP BY c.idclient, c.business_name
HAVING SUM(p.amount) > 100
```

And, because the `client.idclient` column looks very much like a PK, you could probably even omit `client.business_name` from GROUP BY. So the final query would look like this:

```
SELECT c.idclient, c.business_name
FROM payment p
  INNER JOIN client c ON c.idclient = p.idclient
GROUP BY c.idclient
HAVING SUM(p.amount) > 100
```